# convert image src data: into Uint8Array

Tags: javascript

I want to use the ([pica library](https://github.com/nodeca/pica)) for image resize, but it asks me for a Uint8Array and i only have an Image object with the

```
src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ...'
```

I have no idea how to turn this into a Uint8Array, any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: From memory, the data stored in a canvas is stored in a typed array of the same type. So, you could draw the image to a canvas, then call getImageData on the canvas. Inside the returned object, you'll have an array like you wish. Of course, if you're going to go via a canvas anyway you can just do the resize yourself, no need for the library. Here's an example of scaling an image with a canvas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773631/append-canvas-images-to-input-array-with-javascript (just ignore the uploading part)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to apply the image to a canvas and use `getImageData()`.

Here's a simple example of how it can be done:

```
//create canvas, set base64 test img
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    base64 = 'data:image/jpeg;base64...'; //base64 string

//size canvas
canvas.width = 34,
canvas.height = 34;

//create image, set src to base64 and onload draw to canvas
var image = new Image();
image.onload = (function(canvas, ctx){
    return function(){
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

        //now we can finally get a Uint8ClampedArray
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 34, 34);
        console.log(imageData.data);
    };
})(canvas, ctx);
image.src = base64;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Evilzebra/e0ekbvg9/)

Comment: Hi @EvilZebra! Is that possible to get same result from `ctx.getImageData` without using `Image` class ?

Comment: I am afraid not @SergeyVolkov, the only other method available for putting image data into the canvas would be [putImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData) which itself requires a `Uint8ClampedArray`. And we can not easily extract the pixel color data from a base64 encoded image as the string contains image headers and other data.